# Win32+WPF Resizable, Borderless window that has a system menu

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I have a (NoResize Borderless) window in WPF that I am trying to have sizable yet still have the system menu work.
I have manually done NC hittesting to enable resizing and the system menu. However, I can only get one to work at a time. I try to enable both using SetWindowLong(Ptr) but I cannot get any combination to enable the system menu and resizing.
I've tried enabling the `WS_SYSMENU` style which makes no difference.

```
PostMessage(callingWindow, WindowMessage.SystemCommand, new IntPtr(trackPMenu), IntPtr.Zero);
```

only works when the window is not resizable.
Also, setting the window to be an overlapped window (`WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW`) puts a frame around the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MahApps](http://mahapps.com/) OSS project has the ability to have a no resizable borderless window with a system menu. Have a look at there MetroWindow class.

I'm currently using a resizable borderless window with a system menu:

Code behind:

```
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;

public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="XXXX.Views.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                      mc:Ignorable="d"
                      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                      xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:XXXX.ViewModels"
                      xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                      d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:MainViewModel}"
                      WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
                      SaveWindowPosition="True"
                      Title="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=OneWay}"
                      Style="{StaticResource MyCleanWindowStyleKey}">

</controls:MetroWindow>
```

With the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCleanWindowStyleKey"
       TargetType="{x:Type c:MetroWindow}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="TitleForeground"
            Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="TitlebarHeight"
            Value="42" />
    <Setter Property="WindowState"
            Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode"
            Value="CanResizeWithGrip" />
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="TitleCaps"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ShowWindowCommandsOnTop"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="WindowTransitionsEnabled"
            Value="False" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Hmm, looking at the source code for that looks like it does a majority of the window work through native interop (Like including creation)

Comment: is that an issue for you?

Comment: No, just curious at how it did it